# Why would Puppet revoke a client's certificate?

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

We started getting an error from one of the Puppet-agents:

```
Could not send report: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read finished A: sslv3 alert certificate revoked
```

Indeed, according to `puppet cert list $h` on the server, the certificate was revoked. I cleaned it on the master, deleted the `/var/lib/puppet/ssl` on the client and all was fine.

I then ran `puppet cert list --all | grep revoked` -- and found over 20 *other* clients listed as "revoked" too. Spot checking the list I found, that puppet-agent did not have a problem on any of these others.

My questions:

1. What would cause Puppet to "revoke" a particular client's certificate? It certainly was not done by a human administrator...
2. Why would such revokations *not* break things for most clients -- but only for some?

Using puppet-2.7.25 on the clients (RHEL6) and 2.7.18 on the server (RHEL5). Thanks!

Comment: For the ones listed as revoked, do they also have a different cert in inventory for that host that's not revoked?

Comment: Are your certificates expiring? 2.7 has been EOL for some time now. And did someone run `puppet node clean` on the nodes?

Comment: No, actually -- most of the hosts involved are new and their certs are only a few months old. Besides, they aren't listed as "expired" -- but rather as "revoked".

Comment: Shane, no the "revoked" entries are the only ones for each host involved.

Comment: @MikhailT. What web server setup is your puppet master using - the default webrick, or something like Passenger/Apache?  Also, what are the revocation timestamps listed as from `openssl crl -in /var/lib/puppet/ssl/crl.pem -noout -text`?

Comment: Shane, using Apache. That openssl command -- run on one of the clients -- produced *a lot* of output. The revocations listed all claim `Key Compromise` as the reason and some of the dates go back to 2013...

Comment: @MikhailT. How about for the specific nodes that have had the key revoked and are still working - check when they were revoked? (You'll need their serial number - get it from `/var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/inventory.txt`). I'm curious if Apache's restarted since those were added to the CRL - they might only still be working because it only loads the CRL on startup.  If they're recent enough or if a bunch were revoked at once, check in `last` to see whether anyone was on at those times, and in bash history what puppet-related stuff was run around then?